# SwiftUI: Adjusting position of Image in a TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

I use the following code to create a `TabView` with `SwiftUI`:

```
struct TabbedView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            View1().tabItem {
                Image("Tab1")
            }.tag(1)

            View2().tabItem {
                Image("Tab2")
                .offset(y: 20) //<--- has no effect
                }.tag(2)

            View3().tabItem {
                Image("Tab3")
            }.tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

I use only `Image` views for the tab items with no text, the result is as follows:

[image]

I need to position (or vertical-align) the `Image` views down to the center of the `TabView` but couldn't find a straightforward way to do so.

Comment: Please upload one more image of your expected output.

Answer (score 14):

Standard `TabView`does not allow now to change alignment of `tabItem` content... but it is possible to create custom floating tab-like items based on `Button` as below, that would allow to align and/or customise look&feel and still activate TabView items programmatically.

```
struct TabbedView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment.bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $selected) {
                View1().tabItem {
                    Text("") // < invisible tab item
                }.tag(1)

                View2().tabItem {
                    Text("")
                    }.tag(2)

                View3().tabItem {
                    Text("")
                }.tag(3)
            }
            // tab-items cover - do anything needed, height, position, alignment, etc.
            HStack { 
                Button(action: { self.selected = 1 } ) {
                    Image("Tab1") // << align & highlight as needed
                }
                Button(action: { self.selected = 2 } ) {
                    Image("Tab2") // << align & highlight as needed
                }
                Button(action: { self.selected = 3 } ) {
                    Image("Tab3") // << align & highlight as needed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: it can be even w/o buttons, just images with tap gesture, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I found out a trick using extension for UITabBarController

```
extension UITabBarController {
open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let array = self.viewControllers
    for controller in array! {
        controller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: This trick no longer seems to work with new SwiftUI

Answer (score 2):

You can add empty views before images in tabbar, like so:

```
struct TabbedView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            View1().tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Text("")
                    Image("Tab1")
                }
            }.tag(1)
          ...
        }
    }
}
```